# tcpClient.State analogue in vb.net (versus vb6.0)

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcp, vb6, vb6-migration

I used next code in VB6.0 for Winsock object tcpClient:

```
Dim SConst(10) As String
Dim st As Integer

SConst(0) = "Closed"
SConst(1) = "Open"
SConst(2) = "Listening"
SConst(3) = "ConnectionPending"
SConst(4) = "ResolvingHost"
SConst(5) = "HostResolved"
SConst(6) = "Connecting"
SConst(7) = "Connected"
SConst(8) = "Closing"
SConst(9) = "Error"
st = tcpClient.state
TextBox1.Text = SConst(st)
```

Now Im using vb.net and want to do something same.
But there is no `.state` method now for `TcpClient` objects!
There is only `cpClient.Connected` but it returns `Boolean` so only yes or not. How can I do it alike VB6.0?

---

Using [Visual Vinsent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080758/4960953) I made this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim status1 As String
    Dim status2 As String

Private Sub Btn_Connect5001_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)_
                   Handles Btn_Connect5001.Click
        ' Create TcpClient and Connect to
        tcpclnt2 = New TcpClient     
        Try
            tcpclnt2.Connect("192.168.1.177", 5001)
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn_Disconnect5001_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)_
                     Handles Btn_Disconnect5001.Click
        ' Close TcpClient
        tcpclnt2.Close()
    End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ' Check status every 300ms
        status2= New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.177"),5001).GetStatus().ToString()

        TextBox1.Text = Dns.GetHostName + Environment.NewLine +
             "port 1  " + status2 + Environment.NewLine
    End Sub
End Class
```

**The problem is:** At start `status2` is "Unknown", if I connect for the first time `status2` is "Established". If I disconnect it became "TimeWait". But If I connect one more time it stay "TimeWait". It never change its value then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the `TcpClient` nor its underlying `Socket` appears to have such an implementation, so I wrote three extension methods which will get that for you.

What they do is that they iterate every active TCP connection on the computer using the [**`IPGlobalProperties` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) and its [**`GetActiveTcpConnections()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections(v=vs.110).aspx), then they match your connection against the `TcpClient`'s local and remote IP-address.

**Extensions.vb**

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Module Extensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Dynamically gets an object's property by name.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Obj">The object which's property to get.</param>
    ''' <param name="PropertyName">The name of the property to get.</param>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function GetProperty(ByVal Obj As Object, ByVal PropertyName As String) As Object
        Return Obj.GetType().InvokeMember(PropertyName, _
                                           BindingFlags.GetProperty _
                                            Or BindingFlags.IgnoreCase _
                                             Or BindingFlags.Public _
                                              Or BindingFlags.NonPublic _
                                               Or BindingFlags.Instance _
                                                Or BindingFlags.Static, _
                                           Nothing, Obj, Nothing)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the status of a TCP connection.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Client">The TcpClient which's status to get.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function GetStatus(ByVal Client As TcpClient) As TcpState
        If Client Is Nothing OrElse Client.Client Is Nothing Then Return TcpState.Unknown
        For Each TcpConnection As TcpConnectionInformation In IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()

            If TcpConnection.LocalEndPoint.Equals(Client.Client.LocalEndPoint) AndAlso _
                 TcpConnection.RemoteEndPoint.Equals(Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint) Then
                Return TcpConnection.State
            End If

        Next
        Return TcpState.Unknown
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the status of a TCP connection.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="EndPoint">The IPEndPoint (IP-address) of the TCP connection which's status to get.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function GetStatus(ByVal EndPoint As IPEndPoint) As TcpState
        If EndPoint Is Nothing Then Return TcpState.Unknown
        For Each TcpConnection As TcpConnectionInformation In IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()

            If TcpConnection.LocalEndPoint.Equals(EndPoint) OrElse _
                 TcpConnection.RemoteEndPoint.Equals(EndPoint) Then
                Return TcpConnection.State
            End If

        Next
        Return TcpState.Unknown
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the status of a TCP listener.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Listener">The TcpListener which's status to get.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function GetStatus(ByVal Listener As TcpListener) As TcpState
        If Listener Is Nothing OrElse Listener.Server Is Nothing Then Return TcpState.Unknown

        'Per the source code, active listeners will always be in the "Listen" state:
        'https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/SystemIPGlobalProperties.cs,51fa569e558be704
        If Listener.GetProperty("Active") = True Then Return TcpState.Listen

        Return DirectCast(Listener.LocalEndpoint, IPEndPoint).GetStatus() 'The listener is not in an active state.
    End Function
End Module
```

Now to get the status of a connection you have three options:

1. Getting the status of a `TcpClient`:

   ```
   Dim Status As String = yourClient.GetStatus().ToString()
   ```

---

2. Getting the status of a `TcpListener`:

   ```
   Dim Status As String = yourListener.GetStatus().ToString()
   ```

---

3. Getting the status of a connection with the specified IP-address:

   ```
   Dim Status As String = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("your IP-address here"), yourPortHere).GetStatus().ToString()
   ```

**Important notes:**

- The `ToString()` call is necessary if you want the status's name (for example `Established`), otherwise you'll get its enumeration value which is just a normal `Integer` (for example `3`).
- Getting the status of a `TcpClient` or `TcpListener` will only work if neither they nor their underlying `Sockets` are disposed. If you wish to get the status of a ***disconnected*** `TcpClient/-Listener` you have to use **option no. 3** and get it by its exact IP-address and port.

  - Disconnected TCP connections can actually be interesting as well because they still exist after being closed and have a state for a little while. Examples of disconnected states are `CloseWait` or `TimeWait`.

**Read more:**

- [**`IPGlobalProperties` Class - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**`IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()` Method - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**`System.Net.NetworkInformation` Namespace - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**TCP Protocol Operation - Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) (a list of the different TCP connection states)

---

**EDIT:**

To fix the problem with connections lingering in a `CLOSE_WAIT` or `TIME_WAIT` state you can set the underlying `Socket` to linger for 0 seconds and then dispose it. Doing so will cause the socket to perform a so-called "hard close" by sending an `RST` (reset) packet instead of `FIN` (`FIN` is what tells a socket that the connection is closed and that it should go into `CLOSE-/TIME_WAIT`). This method forces the connection to close and no late/retransmitted packets will be mapped to your application after that.

It's actually mentioned on the [**MSDN documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the `l_onoff` member of the linger structure is nonzero and `l_linger` member is zero, `closesocket` is not blocked even if queued data has not yet been sent or acknowledged. This is called a hard or abortive close, because the socket's virtual circuit is reset immediately, and any unsent data is lost. On Windows, any `recv` call on the remote side of the circuit will fail with `WSAECONNRESET`.

This can be done in a simple extension method (put this in the `Extensions` module):

```
''' <summary>
''' Forces the specified TcpClient to close without sending FIN to the other endpoint. This will stop the connection from going into a TIME_WAIT, CLOSE_WAIT or FIN_* state.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Client">The TcpClient to close.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension()> _
Public Sub ForceClose(ByVal Client As TcpClient)
    Client.Client.LingerState = New LingerOption(True, 0) 'Set the socket to linger, but for 0 seconds (causes the current connection to send an RST-packet and terminate).
    Client.Client.Dispose() 'Dispose the underlying socket instead of a graceful shutdown.
    Client.Close() 'Close the TcpClient.
End Sub
```

Then just call it like this:

```
yourClient.ForceClose()
```

Comment: As you see in the Wikipedia article the TCP states are a bit different from VB6's Winsock.

Comment: perfect as always! Thank you for helping me so much! I still not understand all the detail so Im read it now, but I already try this and it works! I create Timer Object and check status of my current IP and ports (your 3d method). But I face one problem: I have "Unknown" value at first, then "Established" after I connect my tcpClient. Thats OK. Then I disconnect my clients (`tcpClient.Close()`) and get "TimeWait". And now I connect again (`New TcpClient` and `.Connect`) but still have "TimeWait" values (expecting "Established" again). So it works only at first connection. What can it be?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : It always shows `Unknown` when the connection doesn't exist. If a connection can be established then it will usually pass the `SynSent` state so fast you won't notice it, hence why it is `Established` immediatelly after.

Comment: Yes, really I never saw `SynSent` value! I suppose it's too fast. But why it isn't `Established` again after I create new TcpClient?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : It shows `TimeWait` or `CloseWait` even after a new connection because the old one (with the same IP and port) still exists and is located earlier in the list. The best would be to find a way to forcibly close the old connection, otherwise check if there are duplicates and return the best option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139338/discussion-between-mikhail-sam-and-visual-vincent).

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : I have updated the answer. Keep in mind that if you're using the new edit then the TCP connection will never go into anything after `Established`.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : The problem is that there is no way to tell for sure which connection is which in the returned list. So unlike VB6 there is no 100% way to accomplish this properly.

Comment: One more interesting moment I found - It is necessary to close TcpClient first and only then close NetworkStream for that client - If I close stream first, I get an error `Cannot access a disposed object`.
And this still doesn't work: i tried `ForceClose()` function but they are still "TimeWait" always after first disconnect.

Comment: I think I should accept answer. I suppose we can't solve the problem in general, but I get statuses as I wished (but yep, they will take correct values one time per 2 minutes :) )

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : I'm afraid so. There is no 100% way to know that you've got the correct status. -- I could reverse the loops so they go backwards, that might help.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : Strange that `ForceClose()` doesn't work, it worked on my machine... When using it you must call that **only**, not any other `Close()/Dispose()` calls on clients nor streams.

Comment: Yep, I deleted all other `Close()` functions and now I'm using `ForceClose` only, but still get the same behavior - All is OK at start and first connection and "TimeWait" for next 2 mins after disconnect

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : Ok then. I will reverse the loops when I get the time. Doing so at least improves the chance a bit...